# how to do an action all the time, when opening the application, except the first opening

Tags: flutter

I search how to make an action for each call of the initstate of my statefull widget exept the first call.

Thank you

Comment: use sharedpreferences plugin

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to use the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin which saves values to local storage.

1. Add the dependency to your pubspec.yaml file

   ```
    dependencies:
         shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
   ```
2. Import the plugin

   ```
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
   ```
3. Reference the SharedPreferences class

   ```
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   ```
4. Lastly check if it is the first time or not

   ```
    // If the preference firstTime does not exist it means it is the first time
    bool firstTime = prefs.getBool('firstTime') ?? true;

    if(firstTime){

      // This is the first time the user is opening the app

      // Set firstTime preference value to false
      await prefs.setBool('firstTime', false);

    } else{
      // The app has been opened before
    }
   ```